# org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type Instant to type org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, graphql-java, spring-framework-beans

I started getting the exception after I upgraded to spring-data-commons-3.2.1 and spring-data-cassandra-4.2.1.

I added the custom conversions

```
@Bean
CassandraCustomConversions cassandraCustomConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new InstantToDateTimeConverter());
    converters.add(new DateTimeToInstantConverter());
    CassandraCustomConversions ccv = new CassandraCustomConversions(converters);
    return ccv;
}
```

but still get the error.

Comment: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.Instant] to type [org.joda.time.DateTime]